# How to run jasmine specs across multiple test directories

Tags: node.js, jasmine, automated-tests

Jasmine is set up to run its specs under a single directory.  It is not set up to find and run tests from multiple spec directories.

Here's my project structure:

```
 project root: /
     package.json
     spec
        --> jasmine_examples
     module_a
        --> spec
     module_b
        --> spec
     module_c
       --> spec
```

If I want to run tests from each of the modules, I have to specify each spec file.

```
    "spec_files": [
      "module_a/spec/spec.js",
      "module_b/spec/spec.js",
      "module_c/spec/spec.js"
    ],
```

This allows me to run the `jasmine` cli but it's not scalable.  There must be a better way.  I don't want to have to manually specify every  module that contains a spec.  I'd like to have all directories recursively searched for specs.

*I'm only running these on Node using JSDom, no Karma or any headless browsers.*

Comment: Have you tried `module_a/spec/*.js` or `module_a/**/*.js`?

Comment: I think that leaves me with the same problem, I still have to manually add each module that contains a spec.

Comment: Then `*/spec/*.js` maybe

Comment: I'm thinking the only way is to use a build script to generate the Jasmine.json files and build out the `spec_files` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `"spec_dir"` property to the root with a double quote ("") then Jasmine will start at the root and traverse the sub-directories.

The problem then will be that the **node_modules** directory will also be included.  So you'll have to use a spec pattern in `spec_files` that's highly unlikely to be be found in there.  I used `["**/*.[sS]pec.js"]` which meant naming my spec files module_a.spec.js.

```
{
  "spec_dir": "",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*.[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

Comment: `The problem then will be that the node_modules directory will also be included. So you'll have to use a spec pattern in spec_files that's highly unlikely to be be found in there.` You can add this as the second `spec_files` pattern instead: `"!node_modules/**"`

Answer (score 2):

You could also seperate your spec files from your source root (what might be src/) to test/ with an equivalent folder structure:

```
project root: /
 package.json
 spec
    --> jasmine_examples
 src/
   module_a
   module_b
   module_c
 test/
   module_a
   module_b
   module_c
```

And then in your jasmine config define spec files like:

```
"spec_files": [
  "test/**/*.spec.js"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to approach this is to set "spec_dir" to root and then use spec_files and glob pattern to match multiple files inside different locations e.g.

```
{
  "spec_dir": "",
  "spec_files": [
    "module_a/**/*.[sS]pec.js",
    "module_b/**/*.[sS]pec.js",
    "module_c/**/*.[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

Following config (located in jasmne.json) will match every "*.spec.js" file inside this module dirs.

You can improve this by moving all modules to common dir e.g. "src" and then change "jasmine.json" to:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "",
  "spec_files": [
    "src/**/*.[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

This will let you forget once and for all about maintenance of this file... and we all know how we devs hate updating all those pesky configs ^^